# Conditional distribution of $X_t = \int_0^t W_s \mathrm{d}s$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

What is the conditional distribution of $$X_t = \int_0^t W_s \mathrm{d}s$$with respect to  $W_t = x$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
X_t = tW_t -\int_0^t sdW_s = \int_0^t (t-s)dW_s,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
W_t = \int_0^t dW_s.
\end{align*}
Then, for any real numbers $a$ and $b$,
\begin{align*}
aX_t + b W_t = \int_0^t (at-as+b)dW_s,
\end{align*}
is normal. That is, $W_t$ and $X_t$ are jointly normal. Moreover. note that
\begin{align*}
E\bigg(W_t\bigg(X_t - \frac{Cov(X_t, W_t)}{Var(W_t)}W_t\bigg)\bigg) = 0.
\end{align*}
That is, $\frac{Cov(X_t, W_t)}{Var(W_t)}W_t= \frac{1}{2}tW_t$ and $X_t-\frac{1}{2}tW_t$ are independent. Given that
\begin{align*}
E(X_t^2) &= \int_0^t(t-s)^2 ds = \frac{1}{3}t^3,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
Var\big(X_t - \frac{1}{2}tW_t\big) = \frac{1}{12}t^3.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
P(X_t \le y \mid W_t) &= P\bigg(X_t - \frac{1}{2}tW_t + \frac{1}{2}tW_t \le y \mid W_t \bigg)\\
&= P\big(X_t - \frac{1}{2}tW_t \le y - \frac{1}{2}tW_t \mid W_t \big)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{y-\frac{1}{2}tW_t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}\pi t^3}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{\frac{1}{6} t^3}} dz.
\end{align*}
That is, the conditional distribution of $X_t$ given $W_t=x$ is normal with the density function
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}\pi t^3}}e^{-\frac{(y-\frac{1}{2}tx )^2}{\frac{1}{6} t^3}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks so much for your Answer...

Comment: You are welcome.